# jQuery - Post and reply

Tags: php, jquery

Im attempting to add voteup/votedown to one of my sites, however Im having a few problems:

Firstly here is my jQuery:

```
j(".voteup").click(function(){ // when people click an up button
  j("div#response").show().html('<h2>voting, please wait...</h2>'); // show wait message
    itemID = j(this).parent('div').attr('id');; // get post id
    alert(itemID);

    j.post(voteup.php,{id:itemID},function(response){ // post to up script
      j("div#response").html(response).hide(3000); // show response
  });

  j(this).attr({"disabled":"disabled"}); // disable button
});
```

My voteup.php file is:

```
<?php

$id=$_POST['itemID'];

echo '<h2>PHP Response: You voted post '.$id.' up</h2>';

?>
```

However It doesnt appear to be working, the alert comes through with the post ID but nothing from then on. The $id doesnt get echo'd.

Any ideas?

Comment: sorry I might get this wrong, but after voting up/down the user is still at the webpage, not be redirected to the voteup.php page, right? So I reckon s/he cannot see the info from that page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must wrote

`$id=$_POST['id'];`

instead of

`$id=$_POST['itemID'];`

in `voteup.php`

Answer (score 0):

I think if you can use json instead of html will be much good but i have a ready to use solution. hope meet your requirement.

http://ad1987.blogspot.com/2009/02/reddit-style-voting-with-php-mysql-and.html
demo is
http://cyberbuff.noadsfree.com/lab/reddit_votes/